# SSIS Merge Join by closest time

Tags: datetime, join, ssis, etl

I have multiple datasources. After many transformations, I end with something like this:

## Datasource1

```
StationId: Id integer
OriginDate: Datetime (i.e. 2011-04-25 16:53:26.623)
```

I have transformed this component to get separated the Year, the month and the day, doing so like this:

```
(DT_I2)YEAR(OriginDate)
```

and the same for the month using `MONTH(OriginDate)` and the  Day.
On the other hand I also have the Time using (`DT_DBTIME)OriginDate`

I made those transformations because I  think they may be useful for my question but not sure about it.
This datasource come from `MSSQL`

## Datasource2

```
CurrentDate (i.e. 01/04/2011)
StationId: Integer
Hour (i.e. 01:59)
```

note that in this ds both fields are varchar.
This datasource comes from `MySQL`

What I need is to join this two datasets by the same `stationId` (easy) and for the closest date (not easy). I should get for each row in Datasource1 the row with the closest time in the other datasource, I mean, for the same Date, the closest time. This is because the datasource2 are measures at a given time, and the datasource1 are events at a given time, and I need to relate them.

How can I achieve this ? The `Merge join component` only allows to join by equals expressions. I would like to avoid staging if possible.

I thought on separate the hour and minutes from both datasources and compare them, and also compare for equality in dates and stationId, but I am not exactly sure how to accomplish the first part of that.

I am stucked with this, about which approach to take.

Comment: The general algorithm would be 'compare every record in dataset 1 with every record in dataset 2 and find the difference in seconds. Pick the lowest seconds'. Are records allowed to match multiple times? What if one record in dataset 1 matches multiple records in dataset 2 or vice versa? IMHO you can't do anything useful in SSIS without staging.

Comment: shouldn't be multiple matches. Let's asume this. If I have to do this with staging how it would be ? Store both datasources and solve it with pure sql ?

Comment: Yes store both datasets and solve with SQL. Either that or write a script transform that takes two inputs and one output. Send the data into the transform ordered and match the closest inside. If you are more comfortable with script then do it that way but I suspect it will perform badly. What if dataset 1 has time 12:30 and dataset 2 has time 12:25 and 12:35. They're equidistant - which one do you pick?

Comment: the lowest maybe, I don't know. Anyway it isn't a "big" problem, because this is not a real life project, it is for university.. I think those things can be just justified with a document as "as designed" :P

Comment: Maybe we should try the script transform first. Take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441678/Getting-Started-With-SSIS-Script-transforms You should be able to add _two_ inputs instead of one. Your inputs must be ordered on stationid, date before they go in. Then there _should_ be a way to write code that allows the two input data flows to interact. It's not obvious to me right now but maybe go through the tutorial first.

Comment: Oh.... so it looks like you can't have two inputs but instead you have to merge the two dataflows into one beforehand with a MERGE transformation, feed that in and process it.